# Setup concurrent web sockets with eventmachine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine

I want to use the websocket-eventmachine-client gem to try to create multiple concurrent web sockets but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Do I need to use EM.defer or something similar?

For instance, I have 20 URLs I need to connect and listen to.
To connect to one I can do:

```
EM.run do
  ws = WebSocket::EventMachine::Client.connect(uri: host)

  ws.onopen do
    p :open
  end

  ws.onmessage do |msg, type|
    p [:message, msg]
  end

  ws.onclose do |code, reason|
    p :closed
  end

  ws.onerror do |error|
    p :error
  end
end
```

What's the code to do that 20 times? So far I've only managed to get connections in serial.

Comment: What code have you tried that gave you connections in serial? Did you try wrapping them all in `defer`?

Comment: I think I just wrapped the code that connects to the stream inside EM.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did:

```
EM.run do
  EM::Iterator.new(connections_list, connections_list.size).each do |conn, iterator|
    # Connection stuff as in question
  end
end
```